# Differences between type and class in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What are the differences between `type` and `class` in Clojure?

```
(type "") => java.lang.String
(class "") => java.lang.String
(type 1) => java.lang.Long
(class 1) => java.lang.Long
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to ClojureDocs

### [type](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/type)

`type` `clojure.core`

`(type x)`

Returns the `:type` metadata of `x`, or its `Class` if none

### [class](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/class)

`class` `clojure.core`

`(class x)`

Returns the `Class` of `x`

So, basically if there're metadata inside `x`, `type` should return its `:type` metadata, otherwise they're the same thing.

Comment: What is a case where the type metadata wouldn't be there? And what adds it?